# Gutenberg Custom Block

Tags: custom-field, block-editor

I am trying to create a custom block for Gutenberg. So I tried something simple as this:

JS File:

```
var el = wp.element.createElement;

wp.blocks.registerBlockType('test/blocks', {
    title: 'Test Blocks',
    icon: 'smiley',
    category: 'common',
    attributes: {
        content: {type: 'string'}
    }
},

edit: function(props) {

    return

    el( 'div', {},
        el( 'p', {}, window.wp.i18n.__( 'Hello World!!!' ) )
    );

},

save: function(props) {           

    return

    el( 'div', {},
        el( 'p', {}, window.wp.i18n.__( 'Hello World!!!' ) )
    );

})
```

The js file is part of a plugin I made and it gets loaded by the .php file. The problem is it doesn't even appear as a block option inside the Gutenberg editor. So my questions are:

1. What's wrong with my current code?
2. How can I add some fields? TextEdit, Button, etc?
3. Is it possible to have multiple fields like a repeater?
4. Why everyone makes a plugin for this? Why not just load the js file from functions.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to 1. You closed registerBlockType too early and to avoid further react errors, you should print your return in the same line as `return` in your edit/save functions.

```
var el = wp.element.createElement;

wp.blocks.registerBlockType('test/blocks', {
    title: 'Test Blocks',
    icon: 'smiley',
    category: 'common',
    attributes: {
        content: {type: 'string'}

    },

edit: function(props) {

    return el( 'div', {},
                el( 'p', {}, window.wp.i18n.__( 'Hello World!!!' ) )
            )
},

save: function(props) {     

    return  el( 'div', {},
                el( 'p', {}, window.wp.i18n.__( 'Hello World!!!' ) )
            );
}
});
```

to 2. You can find elements in the Gutenberg Handbook [here](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/data/data-core/). Notice the search field in the top.
to 3. Where do you want to have multiple fields for what?
to 4. If the block is a plugin it is easy to load and to extend the files. You can also register editor and frontend css files for your block, and it's all in the box. ;o)